# No physics with Scene Editor and custom SKSpriteNode subclass

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

When I set my scene’s node to my `SKSpriteNode` subclass in the scene editor’s Custom Class inspector, the node works as expected (after implementing the `init(coder:_)` method) apart from the physics body on the node.

Here is a screenshot of the node’s Attributes Inspector:

[image: Attributes Inspector]

I notice the Physics Definition is clearly set to none. But as you can see in my `SKSpriteNode`’s subclass’s init methods, I setup the physics body here:

```
required init()
{
    //  Super
    super.init(texture: nil, color: MyColour, size: MySize)

    //  Setup the bubble node
    _setupBubbleNode()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //  Setup the bubble node
    _setupBubbleNode()
}

private func _setupBubbleNode()
{
    //  Properties...
    /// setup stuff...

    //      Physics body
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: _radius)
    physicsBody!.mass = _bubbleMass
    physicsBody!.linearDamping = 20
    physicsBody!.angularDamping = 1
    physicsBody!.restitution = 0.2
    physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true


    //  Other stuff...
    /// setup stuff...
}
```

Note: I should also add that when programatically adding a new instance of my sprite, the physics works…

Comment: Update, using LLDB I’m told the sprite has a physics body: `Optional(<SKPhysicsBody> type:<Circle> representedObject:[<SKSpriteNode> name:'BubbleNode' texture:['nil'] position:{539.91650390625, 588.43157958984375} scale:{1.02, 1.00} size:{102.33232879638672, 100} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00])`.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The item doesn’t fall

Comment: Did you enable gravity on the world

Comment: As I said, when programatically adding them to the scene the nodes fall, but the same subclass when added using the editor does not fall

Comment: The gravity is set as (0, -9.8)

Comment: Ok i am seeing a problem,  can you check to make sure that your node you create on the scene is a member of your subclass, because your printout is saying it is a member of skspritenode

Comment: this print out is true for both the programatic and scene editor nodes. It also must be a subclass as the textures are set in the subclass code only.